# Logic / query required for scenario and pivot is not helping me

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have following table structure

```
ID Status1 status 2 status 3
A1  1       0         1
A1  1       1         0
A2  1       0         0
A3  0       1         1
```

I want to collect it as one record like this (only 1's count for each column)

```
A1 2   1   1
A2 1   1   0
A3 0   1   1
```

I have tried using pivot but actually not the one am getting it correctly.

Please give some thought.

Comment: the result for A2 is showing 2 1 0, what's the logic behind it?

Comment: thanks jayvee, I changed.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you looking for this

```
Select ID, SUM(Status1) As Status1, SUM(Status2) As Status2, SUM(Status3) As Status3
from MyTable
Group By ID
```

Comment: Thanks Snehal, actually I have done in the same way but before I see here.